# Creating synchronous network i/o in Node land

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, networking, io

Are there any blocking `network` I/O libraries for Node.js? We have sync facilities for filesystem I/O, but I am not sure the equivalent exists for network I/O in Node.js.

We can create blocking network action like so:

```
var available = true;
var messages = [];
var socket = io('http://localhost:8080');

socket.on('RESPONSE_RECEIVED', function () {
    available = true;  //we can confirm receipt, so we are free to process next message
    var msg = messages.shift();
    if (msg) {
        sendData(msg);
    }
});

function sendData(data) {
    if (available) {
        available = false;
        socket.emit('SEND_NEW_DATA', data);
    } else {
        messages.push(data);
    }
}
```

I have confirmed that this works pretty well..the socket connection waits for a response before processing the next message. If the socket is "busy" we just push on a new message on the queue. So it's a message queue.

Just wondering if there's anything lower level that we could use. I doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js is built on libuv which **polls non-blocking network sockets** for activity. From the [libuv design overview](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html#the-i-o-loop) document (emphasis added):

> The event loop follows the rather usual single threaded asynchronous I/O approach: **all (network) I/O is performed on non-blocking sockets** which are polled using the best mechanism available on the given platform: epoll on Linux, kqueue on OSX and other BSDs, event ports on SunOS and IOCP on Windows.

However, if a Node.js app has only one I/O operation and no timers, then **the poll will block indefinitely**.

> 7. Poll timeout is calculated. Before blocking for I/O the loop calculates for how long it should block. These are the rules when calculating the timeout:
>
>    - If the loop was run with the UV_RUN_NOWAIT flag, the timeout is 0.
>    - If the loop is going to be stopped (uv_stop() was called), the timeout is 0.
>    - If there are no active handles or requests, the timeout is 0.
>    - If there are any idle handles active, the timeout is 0.
>    - If there are any handles pending to be closed, the timeout is 0.
>    - If none of the above cases was matched, the timeout of the closest timer is taken, or if there are no active timers, **infinity**.
> 8. The loop blocks for I/O. At this point the loop will block for I/O for the timeout calculated on the previous step. All I/O related handles that were monitoring a given file descriptor for a read or write operation get their callbacks called at this point.

So no, there are no Node.js libraries that can guarantee synchronous network I/O. But, it's possible to write a small, probably useless Node.js app that effectively polls a non-blocking socket indefinitely. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, from your answer, it's not clear to me what the difference is between "poll indefinitely" and "poll until the response is ready/done", they seem the same to me